# What are the possible status values when using delivery notifications?

Tags: clickatell

I am setting up integration with a new Clickatell account.  Our old account posts statuses like 003, 004 etc.  They can be found here https://archive.clickatell.com/developers/api-docs/message-status-codes/

The new account seems to post statuses like this 'DELIVERED_TO_GATEWAY'.  Is there a list of the possible statuses somewhere?

Comment: So far I have seen DELIVERED_TO_GATEWAY, RECEIVED_BY_RECIPIENT, ERROR_DELIVERING and FAILED